# chroot cannot find cgi file

Tags: webserver, chroot, openbsd, cgi

I am unable to serve or execute a cgi file, and the cause seems to be that chroot is unable to find the cgi file when the permission is set to executable.

```
$>ls -l /var/www/my/dir/test.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   daemon 67 May 19 15:45 /var/www/my/dir/test.cgi

$> chroot /var/www/ /my/dir/test.cgi
chroot: /my/dir/test.cgi: No such file or directory
```

Why can chroot not find the file?

If I change the permissions to remove execution, `$> chmod 644 /var/www/my/dir/test.cgi`, then run the same chroot command, the file is found, but permission is denied.

```
$> chroot /var/www/ /my/dir/test.cgi
chroot: /my/dir/test.cgi: Permission denied
```

The system is OpenBSD 5.7. I was testing using chroot to try to mimic what the httpd webserver does, because in the log /var/log/daemon, there is a similar message from slowcgi after trying to access the file: `slowcgi[15587] execve /my/dir/index.cgi: No such file or directory`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Test.cgi looks pretty small. Is it a shell script? Is the shell available inside the chroot environment?

Comment: actually the shell is not available I think. If I just enter `$> chroot /var/www` i get an error saying no shell is found. how should i set that?

Comment: the test.cgi file is just a tIny `print 'hello'` perl script with shebang on top

Comment: I'll defer to someone with more openbsd experience than I have. There's surely a straightforward method to install shell and perl and their dependencies in an alternative root, but I don't know offhand how to do it.

Comment: oo just found [this]( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E36387/html/ol_cj_sec.html) about using `ldd <command>` to find required dependencies for any command, then just copy paste em into same directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need `perl` and all the dependencies of it in your `chroot`.

This files all have to be copied over to `/var/www/usr/bin`, `/var/www/usr/lib` and `/var/www/usr/libexec`:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl:
        Start            End              Type Open Ref GrpRef Name
        0000001b26c00000 0000001b27002000 exe  1    0   0      /usr/bin/perl
        0000001da0006000 0000001da0418000 rlib 0    2   0      /usr/lib/libpthread.so.18.1
        0000001d2b68b000 0000001d2bc26000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libperl.so.17.0
        0000001d6fed5000 0000001d702fd000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libm.so.9.0
        0000001d8d017000 0000001d8d423000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libutil.so.12.1
        0000001ddb924000 0000001ddbe10000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libc.so.78.1
        0000001d7f700000 0000001d7f700000 rtld 0    1   0      /usr/libexec/ld.so
```

Comment: True that, along with all the perl modules used by the cgi script.